# Trying to access custom post redirects to home page

Tags: custom-post-types

I just started using WordPress and it seems I need more practice and advice to make it behave the way I want it to.
I inherited an already working site from another guy. Now I have to actually add new functionality to it, but I got stuck.
I am trying to add a custom post type and make posts of that type actually show.
For that, I mostly copy-pasted code from other places in the site.
The code I use to create a new post category is the following:

```
  function theme_setup() {

    //Other code that creates other post categories


    //My new stuff
    register_post_type(
        'contest',
        array(
            'label' => 'Concursuri',
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,/*below Posts*/
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
            'taxonomies' => array('contests'),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => 'contest',
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'contest/%categorie%', 'with_front' => false),
            'feeds' => true, 'pages' => true,
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'contests',
        'contest',
        array(
            'label' => 'Categorii Concursuri',
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'contest', 'with_front' => false),
        )
    );

    //Then some other stuff, and at the end:

    //flush_rewrite_rules(false); //Removed and using visit to permalink instead
}
add_action('init', 'theme_setup');



add_filter('post_type_link', 'events_permalink_structure', 10, 3);
function events_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename) {
    $arr = array(
        //Some elements here, then mine
        'contest' => 'contests',
        //Some more elements here
    );
    foreach ($arr as $post_type => $tax) {
        if ($post->post_type == $post_type) {
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $tax);
            if (!empty($terms)) // link of the form http://www.site.com/<taxonomie>/%categorie%/<nume>
                $post_link = str_replace('%categorie%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link);
            else // link of the form http://www.site.com/<taxonomie>/%material%
                $post_link = str_replace('/%categorie%', "", $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}

function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newrules = array();
    //Some other similar rules, then my new rule
    $newrules['^contest/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?'] = 'index.php?post_type=contest&contest=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Now, after adding this code to functions.php, I get a new link in the admin page, which allows me to add new posts of this type.

I can add them (no problem), I can preview them by accessing a link like '**?post_type=contest&p=2873&preview=true**', I can even

query them after posting with code like this:

```
            <?php
            $query = new WP_Query(array(
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'post_type' => 'contest',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            ));
            if ($query->found_posts) { ?>

            ...display a list of posts in some way...

            <?php } wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

However, when I try to actually access the post, it redirects me to the homepage. This happens from the links I created (they look like this: '**/contest/#post-2873**' - which is similar to other links created for other custom posts), from the edit page from WordPress (which looks like this: '**/contest/test/**'), or if I manually enter the url like: '**?post_type=contest&p=2873**'.
Trying to access '**/contest/**' also redirects me to my homepage.

I searched for similar problems, which suggest I should visit the permalinks page before trying again. I did that, and also pressed 'Save Changes' in there, but it still doesn't work.

I also tried other stuff, like not adding a rewrite rule for this, but the results are always the same.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but I don't know what.

Can you please help me solve this one? I don't necessarily want to play with php, so if there is an UI for doing what I'm trying to do, that would also be great.

Thanks!

Edit: it's been a couple of days, still no results. Tried other stuff, such as editing .htaccess, making a custom type with a different name, not adding a taxonomy, and so on. No results yet. Help!

Comment: why do you have `hierarchical` argument in the `rewrite` argument array

Comment: Also don't use flush_rewrite_rules on the `init` hook.Flush rules only on activation or deactivation.

Comment: @bravokeyl I removed the hierarchical arguments and stopped using flush_rewrite_rules on the init, visiting instead the permalinks to refresh the rules. Still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: what's the permalink structure you want for `contest` single post type ?

Comment: Hmm, something like this happened to me recently and it was because the template that I was calling the custom post type loop was assigned as a "Front Page" in the settings > reading area on the dashboard. But in your case, it's not the blogroll of your custom post type - it's the posts themselves? Also try putting the permalinks to default if it isn't already with no re-write rules, and see if you can access the posts.